# build C++ DLL with specific MFC version

Tags: c++, build

I have a DLL project in VStudio2008+SP. The MFC version I have running is 9.0.3070, I have also installed the 9.0.21xxx in C:\Windows\WinSxS\
When I build my DLL it reference the 9.0.3070, when it is used in client PC we fail to load it because there is only the 9.0.21 on client's workstation.
I would like to know if it is possible to force the build of DLL using specific MFC version.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is not possible. Once you have installed VS2008 Service Pack, MFC version 9.0.3070 is hardcoded in MFC sources, and you can't change it except by uninstalling SP.

You should make the installer of your application to install the required version of MFC on the client's machine.